# Multiple dependency Issue with NPM and ng2

Tags: angular, npm, ionic2

I working on an IONIC app, but when I tried to install some packages they requires some versions of other packages, but when I change those, other packages needs the version I was using before.
Is there a way I can have everything working togheter? Sorry if it is an stupid question...

FOr example:
If I have `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12`
I get:

```
angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
```

But if I changed for the suggested one and I run npm install I get:

```
@angular/core@2.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed
```

The same happens when I try to run:

```
npm i ionic2-input-mask --save
```

I get several UNMEET PEER DEPENDENCY... but when I change those in the package.json I get another errors..

Comment: try a lower version of angularfire2 ? which dependency match rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12?

Comment: But it happens with several packages... So I need to find a balance between all of them? Is that usually possible? with ionic2-input-mask I get 4 or 5 conflicts in the common/ core / form package so I guess that will be complicated to balance

Comment: hmm.. https://github.com/joshuamorony/ionic2-input-mask/blob/master/package.json this itself is based on ionic RC4..whihc is why you are getting dependency problems..

Comment: Yes... so.. is there any way I can include that with my current versions? Or which is the suggested aproach for these cases?